# Confusion with Preprocessor Directives

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, ifndef

I have three files

File "grandparent.h"

```
#ifndef GRANDPARENT_H
#define GRANDPARENT_H

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif /* GRANDPARENT_H */
```

File "parent.h"

```
#include "grandparent.h"
```

File "child.c"

```
 #include "grandparent.h"
 #include "parent.h"
```

Wiki says

> Here, the first inclusion of "grandparent.h" causes the macro
>   GRANDPARENT_H to be defined. Then, when "child.c" includes
>   "grandparent.h" the second time, the #ifndef test returns false, and
>   the preprocessor skips down to the #endif, thus avoiding the second
>   definition of struct foo. The program compiles correctly.

q1. "the first inclusion of "grandparent.h" causes the **macro**
 GRANDPARENT_H **to be defined**", So what i understand i its basically **defining a macro named `GRANDPARENT_H`** but what i dont understand is that how will the content of that macro  (i.e GRANDPARENT_H) would be included in the child.c.

We are just defining  the macro GRANDPARENT_H 
i.e

```
#define GRANDPARENT_H

struct foo {
    int member;
};
```

but how will its content i.e

```
struct foo {
    int member;
};
```

be included in the child.c

Comment: it has no value. It's just defined to ensure that the types & functions definitions just are evaluated once by the compiler.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre do you mean that the macro GRANDPARENT_H is empty

Comment: Perhaps what you may want to do is just run your code through the preprocessor, and see how everything is expanded, and yes `GRANDPARENT_H` is empty

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem can you help me with that

Comment: Just run `gcc -E` to get the code after preprocessor has done its thing, check the documentation for the compiler you're using if not gcc. Clang uses the same `-E` flag it seems (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html)

Comment: @rimiro you can write `#define FOO 123`. Then the preprocesseur symbol `FOO` is defined and each time you write `FOO`, `FOO` will be replaced by `123`. But you can also write `#define FOO`. Then the preprocesseur symbol `FOO`is also defined and each time you write `FOO`, `FOO` will be replaced by, you've guessed it, an empty string.

Comment: The content of the macro is only what's beyond it on its line, not the file content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you "expand" `child.c` manually until there are no `#include` left:

```
//grandparent.h

#ifndef GRANDPARENT_H    // <- not defined at this point
#define GRANDPARENT_H    // <- now it's defined

struct foo {
    int member;
};

#endif /* GRANDPARENT_H */
//parent.h

//#include "grandparent.h" resolves into
//grandparent.h

#ifndef GRANDPARENT_H   // <- already defined, skip until matching #endif
#define GRANDPARENT_H   // <- not executed by preprocessor

struct foo {            // <- not provided to the compiler
    int member;
};

#endif /* GRANDPARENT_H */
```

now read it sequentially.
The first line checks if macro `GRANDPARENT_H` is defined. Obviously it is not, as it's the first instruction of the code.

The second line defines `GRANDPARENT_H` macro. It's empty but that's no important, what's important is that it is *defined*.

Then, the code defines your struct...

When the preprocessor encounters the second `#ifdef GRANDPARENT_H`, the macro is already defined, so it skips the whole contents of the file and you don't get any `foo redefined` error.

Which is confirmed by using `-E` option to see preprocessed `child.c` file:

```
$ gcc -E child.c
# 1 "child.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "child.c"
# 1 "grandparent.h" 1


struct foo {
    int member;
};
# 2 "child.c" 2
# 1 "parent.h" 1
# 2 "child.c" 2
```

as you can see, the structure is only defined once.

Note that most compilers now support a simpler way to do this: just insert

```
#pragma once
```

at the start of your file. Like this:

```
#pragma once

struct foo {
    int member;
};
```

that's it!

Comment: So when we write `#define GRANDPARENT_H` we are defining a empty macro and it has nothing to do with the line below it?? Please answer this thats the last thing confusing me

Comment: @rimiro yes that's it.